# Windows 10 taskbar drag and start new instant, make Chrome launch with the main profile?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, taskbar

I have set "Combine taskbar buttons" to "When taskbar is full".

My favourite way of starting a new instance (or a window) of an application is to drag the taskbar item up, and to click the application name. I have a main profile and several test profiles. It seems that Chrome always launches with the lastly used profile, not with the main profile, when I drag up from the taskbar.

Is it possible to make Chrome always launch with the main profile?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add the profile you want to start to the command line to the shortcut.

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Default"`

If you want to have a shortcut to any other profile, just replace `Default` with the name of the profile.. All profiles are located under `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data`.